# Paned Window in Visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Which control do I use in Visual C# to create a paned window?

This is what I mean:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: WinForm? WPF? ASP.NET? Metr... err... Modern Windows-store-style app?

Comment: My question refers to windows forms.

Comment: Penguin display pic, so we may as well mention Gtk#

Comment: @Alex: Haha... good catch, i love that... :)

Comment: Are you trying to exactly emulate a third party control?  How many panes? Do you need the visual queue's?  Resizing, overflow...?  Because you could drop a Panel or two down throw up a border and call it a day unless you need one of a million unique features better suited to specialized controls.

Comment: Windows Forms: SplitContainer is your control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you can use the [SplitContainer-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h0w5ctby.aspx) to divide your windows in multiple sections/panes.

You can use its [Dock-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.dock.aspx) to set the width and height to the parents size

```
splitContainer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill //Sets the size to the one's of the parent container
```

Further you can set if the splitter is vertical or horizontal with following code:
[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.orientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
splitContainer1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; //Or Orientation.Vertical
```

To show the borders of the SplitContainer you can use the [BorderStyle-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.borderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
splitContainer1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D; //3d-Effect
//BorderStyle.FixedSingle; //Shown in the example
//BorderStyle.None; //No borders
```

Finally you can get following result for example:
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for not trivializing a VC# beginner's question. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Everyone has to start somewhere ;) But a small advice:  If you have a little spare time just take a look at the available controls and check MSDN for further information. That way you'll get familiar with most of the controls

Comment: Okay. I am just familarizing with the common patterns in the MS programming world..