# draggable separator C windows control?

Tags: c, windows, separator, common-controls

In many windows such as Device-Manager and Regedit, we see a vertical separator that divides two white child windows. These separators can be dragged side to side using the mouse.

Is there a windows control or native common control that can be used to create this effect?

I couldn't find anything on MSDN, and spent all last weekend trying to emulate the behavior using various combinations of child windows and custom resize-handling.

I'm specifically asking in regard to the C API, IE CreateWindowEx(), etc.

Thanks

Comment: In some other toolkits (like gtk)  this is called a "paned window widget". Trying to find the native Windows equivalent... [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19691727/2404501). A general search for [Windows "pane control"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+%22pane+control%22) suggests that this is the right name, but I can't make much sense of the pages it finds.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, It looks like you're onto something there. Some of those other pages are referring to it as a split-container control. Those pages look like they're for the C++ .NETish API (System.yadda.yadda stuff), an odd windows forms markup, and VBC# though. I did notice though that a screenshot they showed looked exactly like carefully arranged MDI-clients. Maybe there's some way to configure MDI-clients to behave this way.

Comment: It is called a **Splitter** window. There are several old samples in SDK, some were written in C/16-bits (SDK 3.1) and still work.